# Prove that family F of given set X is an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I have to prove that for given set $X$ a family defined $F = \{A \subset X: A \ \text{is finite or} \ A^{c}\  \text{is finite}\}  $,
where $A^{c}$ is a compliment of subset $A$ is an algebra.

As I suppose, I have to show that three statements are true.

First of all, $\emptyset$ is finite subset of $X$, so it's obvious that $\emptyset \in F$.

Second condition, we have to show that $A,B \in F \Rightarrow A\cup B\in F$.
If both $A$ and $B$ are finite that obviously $A \cup B \in F$. If $A$ is infinite and $B$ is finite then from de Morgan's law we get $(A\cup B)^{c} = A^{c}\cap B^{c}$ which is finite because $A^{c}$ is finite.
Third case, both $A$ and $B$ are infinite, so again from de Morgan's law 
$(A\cup B)^{c} = A^{c} \cap B^{c}$ which is finite.

Finally, third condition $A^{c} = X \setminus A \in F$ either $A$ is finite or $A^c$ is finite.

Is it correct?

Comment: Does "algebra" here mean $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: It means it's closed for finite sums, not infinite.

Comment: Your proof seems correct then